# How do I format a number with commas in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm running some administrative queries and compiling results from `sp_spaceused` in SQL Server 2008 to look at data/index space ratios of some tables in my database.  Of course I am getting all sorts of large numbers in the results and my eyes are starting to gloss over.  It would be really convenient if I could format all those numbers with commas (987654321 becomes 987,654,321).  Funny that in all the many years I've used SQL Server, this issue has never come up since most of the time I would be doing formatting at the presentation layer, but in this case the T-SQL result in SSMS **is** the presentation.

I've considered just creating a simple CLR UDF to solve this, but it seems like this should be do-able in just plain old T-SQL.  So, I'll pose the question here - how do you do numeric formatting in vanilla T-SQL?

Comment: Does "Reports -> Disk Usage by Table" do what you need in an aesthetically pleasing enough way?

Comment: @Martin - Truly awesome!  Didn't even know that existed.  I've carried some of my DBA scripts with me for nearly a decade, so I missed that entirely.  Still, I think this question is an important part of the T-SQL knowledge base on stackoverflow, but for my specific problem this is really handy.

Comment: With SQL Server 2012 + You can use the FORMAT() function. e.g. '#,##.000' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Answer (score 314, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 and higher, this will format a number with commas:

```
select format([Number], 'N0')
```

You can also change `0` to the number of decimal places you want.

Comment: This is now the best answer since the introduction of the `format` function.

Comment: it's worth noticing the third (optional) parameter `culture`.

Comment: OP specified SQL Server 2008

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of a prior answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16040511/125981 with less information.

Answer (score 270):

While I agree with everyone, including the OP, who says that formatting should be done in the presentation layer, this formatting can be accomplished in T-SQL by casting to `money` and then converting to `varchar`. This does include trailing decimals, though, that could be looped off with `SUBSTRING`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(987654321 AS money), 1)
```

Comment: While I agree that generally formatting should happen elsewhere, we all take the date formatting functions for granted.  Comma insertion can be done as shown here.  +1.

Comment: However, this does not work for other mony-formatting-styles. In Switzerland we write Money for instance in this form:
987'654'321.00

How to do that?

Comment: You could do a replace SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CAST(987654321 AS money), 1),',','''')

Comment: While I agree that formatting should be done in the presentation layer where possible, there are certainly times, such as with Ignite/DPA alerts, that the email I receive is the presentation layer. The only way to put commas in a place such as that is through SQL. Having commas in large numbers is extraordinarily helpful in those cases.

Comment: Everyone wants to tell you what "should" be done, but that's not what designing your own code is about. If everyone only did what "should" be done, then we lose that spirit of inventiveness and ability to hack things together to solve a problem quickly with minimal fuss and effort.

Comment: Where can I get the complete list of CONVERT VARCHAR STYLES? Because I don't know where that "1" Style came from?

Answer (score 60):

I'd recommend Replace in lieu of Substring to avoid string length issues:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(20), (CAST(SUM(table.value) AS money)), 1), '.00', '')
```

Comment: Even though the money conversion shouldn't ever change, I like the guarantee of not going out of bounds that Replace offers over Substring.

Comment: If you accidentally feed it a decimal you would still get the first two decimal places in your output as well.

Answer (score 57):

For SQL Server 2012+ implementations, you will have the ability to use the [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) to apply string formatting to non-string data types.

In the original question, the user had requested the ability to use commas as thousands separators. In a [closed as duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039825/format-dollar-amount-for-a-tsql-query), the user had asked how they could apply currency formatting. The following query shows how to perform both tasks. It also demonstrates the application of culture to make this a more generic solution (addressing Tsiridis Dimitris's function to apply Greek special formatting)

```
-- FORMAT
-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx
-- FORMAT does not do conversion, that's the domain of cast/convert/parse etc
-- Only accepts numeric and date/time data types for formatting. 
--
-- Formatting Types
-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx

-- Standard numeric format strings
-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx
SELECT
    -- c => currency
    -- n => numeric
    FORMAT(987654321, N'N', C.culture) AS some_number
,   FORMAT(987654321, N'c', C.culture) AS some_currency
,   C.culture
FROM
    (
        -- Language culture names
        -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx
        VALUES
            ('en-US')
        ,   ('en-GB')
        ,   ('ja-JP')
        ,   ('Ro-RO')
        ,   ('el-GR')
    ) C (culture);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3545/0) for the above

Comment: Great share, this will come in handy :)

Comment: Fiddle is broken, it now says `String index out of range: 33`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Yeah, it's a pity that the fiddle for SQL Server no longer works. Fortunately, you should be able to paste the above into any query tool that is connected to SQL Server 2012+

Answer (score 26):

#### Demo 1

Demonstrates adding commas:

```
PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('The number is: %s', format(5000000, '#,##0'))
-- Output
The number is: 5,000,000
```

#### Demo 2

Demonstrates commas and decimal points. Observe that it rounds the last digit if necessary.

```
PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('The number is: %s', format(5000000.759145678, '#,##0.00'))
-- Output
The number is: 5,000,000.76
```

#### Compatibility

`SQL Server 2012+`.

Comment: This is the one! Works with len(column) as well as just column - whereas another 2012+ solution I tried didn't.

Comment: Great! This is the answer I was looking for (for use with T-SQL, including [on **SEDE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/876980/t-sql-format-number-with-commas-between-thousands))

Answer (score 19):

Please try with below query:

```
SELECT FORMAT(987654321,'#,###,##0')
```

Format with right decimal point :

```
SELECT FORMAT(987654321,'#,###,##0.###\,###')
```

Comment: Yes, the right way now that we have the `FORMAT` function is `SELECT format(123456789987654321,'###,##0')`, or more simply, `select format(123456789987654321, 'N0')` as @ThomasMueller answered.

Comment: FORMAT is a performance nightmare - you start using it and depend on it, then find that your database can't scale up.  And now it's built into a dozen features and you can't escape it.

Never use FORMAT.

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(20), (CAST(9876543 AS money)), 1), '.00', '')
```

output=  9,876,543

and you can replace 9876543 by your column name.

Answer (score 8):

Tried the money trick above, and this works great for numerical values with two or less significant digits. I created my own function to format numbers with decimals:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_FormatWithCommas] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @value varchar(50)
)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @WholeNumber varchar(50) = NULL, @Decimal varchar(10) = '', @CharIndex int = charindex('.', @value)

    IF (@CharIndex > 0)
        SELECT @WholeNumber = SUBSTRING(@value, 1, @CharIndex-1), @Decimal = SUBSTRING(@value, @CharIndex, LEN(@value))
    ELSE
        SET @WholeNumber = @value

    IF(LEN(@WholeNumber) > 3)
        SET @WholeNumber = dbo.fn_FormatWithCommas(SUBSTRING(@WholeNumber, 1, LEN(@WholeNumber)-3)) + ',' + RIGHT(@WholeNumber, 3)



    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @WholeNumber + @Decimal

END
```

Answer (score 4):

This belongs in a comment to [Phil Hunt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492543/phil-hunt)'s answer but alas I don't have the rep.

To strip the ".00" off the end of your number string, parsename is super-handy. 
 It tokenizes period-delimited strings and returns the specified element, starting with the rightmost token as element 1.

```
SELECT PARSENAME(CONVERT(varchar, CAST(987654321 AS money), 1), 2)
```

Yields "987,654,321"

Comment: You're using a vendor-specific function for object name parsing?  Cool if it just really splits on '.' in the string, but you're pretty close to violating the intent of PARESENAME() function when using it for number formatting.  I'd fail that in a code review for my team, IOW I wouldn't call it a "professional-level answer".  I'd call it more "dev trick" in the vein of old late-night "stupid human tricks".

Answer (score 3):

here is another t-sql UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Format(@num int)
returns varChar(30)
As
Begin
Declare @out varChar(30) = ''

  while @num > 0 Begin
      Set @out = str(@num % 1000, 3, 0) + Coalesce(','+@out, '')
      Set @num = @num / 1000
  End
  Return @out
End
```

Answer (score 2):

```
`/* Author: Tsiridis Dimitris */
/* Greek amount format. For the other change the change on replace of '.' & ',' */
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.formatAmount  (
@amtIn as varchar(20)
) RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN 

return cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), CAST(@amtIn AS money), 1),1,
LEN(CONVERT(varchar(20), CAST(@amtIn AS money), 1))-3), ',','.')
 + replace(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(20), CAST(@amtIn AS money), 1),3), '.',',') AS VARCHAR(20))

END

SELECT [geniki].[dbo].[formatAmount]('9888777666555.44')`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a scalar function I am using that fixes some bugs in a previous example (above) and also handles decimal values (to the specified # of digits) (EDITED to also work with 0 & negative numbers).  One other note, the cast as money method above is limited to the size of the MONEY data type, and doesn't work with 4 (or more) digits decimals.  That method is definitely simpler but less flexible.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnNumericWithCommas](@num decimal(38, 18), @decimals int = 4) RETURNS varchar(44) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret varchar(44)

    DECLARE @negative bit; SET @negative = CASE WHEN @num < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

    SET @num = abs(round(@num, @decimals)) -- round the value to the number of decimals desired
    DECLARE @decValue varchar(18); SET @decValue = substring(ltrim(@num - round(@num, 0, 1)) + '000000000000000000', 3, @decimals)
    SET @num = round(@num, 0, 1) -- truncate the incoming number of any decimals
    WHILE @num > 0 BEGIN
        SET @ret = str(@num % 1000, 3, 0) + isnull(','+@ret, '')
        SET @num = round(@num / 1000, 0, 1)
    END
    SET @ret = isnull(replace(ltrim(@ret), ' ', '0'), '0') + '.' + @decValue
    IF (@negative = 1) SET @ret = '-' + @ret

    RETURN @ret
END

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Another UDF which is hopefully generic enough and does not make assumptions about whether you want to round to a specific number of decimal places:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_FormatNumber] (@number decimal(38,18))

RETURNS varchar(50)

BEGIN
    -- remove minus sign before applying thousands seperator
    DECLARE @negative bit
    SET @negative = CASE WHEN @number < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    SET @number = ABS(@number)

    -- add thousands seperator for every 3 digits to the left of the decimal place
    DECLARE @pos int, @result varchar(50) = CAST(@number AS varchar(50))
    SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @result)
    WHILE @pos > 4
    BEGIN
        SET @result = STUFF(@result, @pos-3, 0, ',')
        SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @result)
    END

    -- remove trailing zeros
    WHILE RIGHT(@result, 1) = '0'
        SET @result = LEFT(@result, LEN(@result)-1)
    -- remove decimal place if not required
    IF RIGHT(@result, 1) = '.'
        SET @result = LEFT(@result, LEN(@result)-1)

    IF @negative = 1
        SET @result = '-' + @result

    RETURN @result
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
  #------------------------------------------------------------------------#
  #            SQL Query Script                                            #
  #            ----------------                                            #
  # Funcion.:  dbo.fn_nDerecha ( Numero, Pos_Enteros, Pos_Decimales )      #
  #    Numero        : es el Numero o Valor a formatear                    #
  #    Pos_Enteros   : es la cantidad posiciones para Enteros              #
  #    Pos_Decimales : es la cantidad posiciones para Decimales            #
  #                                                                        #
  # OBJETIVO:  Formatear los Numeros con Coma y Justificado a la Derecha   #
  #  Por Ejemplo:                                                          #
  #   dbo.fn_nDerecha ( Numero, 9, 2 )         Resultado = ---,---,--9.99  #
  #               dado  Numero = 1234.56       Resultado =       1,234.56  #
  #               dado  Numero = -1.56         Resultado =          -1.56  #
  #               dado  Numero = -53783423.56  Resultado = -53,783,423.56  #
  #                                                                        #
  # Autor...:  Francisco Eugenio Cabrera Perez                             #
  # Fecha...:  Noviembre 25, 2015                                          #
  # Pais....:  Republica Dominicana                                        #
  #------------------------------------------------------------------------#
*/



CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_nDerecha]
(
    -- Agregue Argumentos, para personalizar la funcion a su conveniencia
    @Numero_str    varchar(max)
   ,@Pos_Enteros   int
   ,@Pos_Decimales int
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  --  Declare la variable del RETURN aqui, en este caso es RESULT
  declare @RESULTADO varchar(max)
  set     @RESULTADO = '****'

  -----------------------------------------------  --
  declare @Numero_num numeric(28,12)
  set     @Numero_num =
  (
  case when isnumeric(@Numero_str) = 0 
       then 0
       else round (convert( numeric(28,12), @Numero_str), @Pos_Decimales)
  end
  )
  --  -----------------------------------------------  --
  --  Aumenta @Pos_Enteros de @RESULTADO,
  --      si las posiciones de Enteros del dato @Numero_str es Mayor...
  --
  declare   @Num_Pos_Ent int
  set       @Num_Pos_Ent = len ( convert( varchar, convert(int, abs(@Numero_num) ) ) )
  --
  declare   @Pos_Ent_Mas int
  set       @Pos_Ent_Mas =
  (
  case when @Num_Pos_Ent > @Pos_Enteros
       then @Num_Pos_Ent - @Pos_Enteros
       else 0
  end
  )
  set       @Pos_Enteros = @Pos_Enteros + @Pos_Ent_Mas
  --
  --  -----------------------------------------------  --
  declare @p_Signo_ctd       int
  set     @p_Signo_ctd       = (case when @Numero_num < 1 then 1 else 0 end)
  --
  declare @p_Comas_ctd       int
  set     @p_Comas_ctd       = ( @Pos_Enteros - 1 ) / 3
  --
  declare @p_Punto_ctd       int
  set     @p_Punto_ctd       = (case when @Pos_Decimales > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
  --
  declare @p_input_Longitud  int
  set     @p_input_Longitud  = ( @p_Signo_ctd + @Pos_Enteros ) +
                                 @p_Punto_ctd + @Pos_Decimales
  --
  declare @p_output_Longitud int
  set     @p_output_Longitud = ( @p_Signo_ctd + @Pos_Enteros   + @p_Comas_ctd )
                             + ( @p_Punto_ctd + @Pos_Decimales )
  --
  --  ===================================================================  --


  declare @Valor_str varchar(max)
  set     @Valor_str = str(@Numero_num, @p_input_Longitud, @Pos_Decimales)

  declare @V_Ent_str varchar(max)
  set     @V_Ent_str = 
  (case when @Pos_Decimales > 0 
        then substring( @Valor_str, 0, charindex('.', @Valor_str, 0) )
        else            @Valor_str end)
  --
  declare @V_Dec_str varchar(max)
  set     @V_Dec_str = 
  (case when @Pos_Decimales > 0 
        then '.' + right(@Valor_str, @Pos_Decimales)
        else '' end)
  --
  set @V_Ent_str = convert(VARCHAR, convert(money, @V_Ent_str), 1) 
  set @V_Ent_str = substring( @V_Ent_str, 0, charindex('.', @V_Ent_str, 0) )
  --


  set @RESULTADO    = @V_Ent_str + @V_Dec_str 
  --
  set @RESULTADO = ( replicate( ' ', @p_output_Longitud - len(@RESULTADO) ) + @RESULTADO )
  --

  --  ===================================================================  -
```

### --  ===================================================================  -

```
  RETURN @RESULTADO
END

  --  ===================================================================  --
```

/*
This function needs 3 arguments: the First argument is the @Numero_str which the Number as data input, and the other 2 arguments specify how the information will be formatted for the output, those arguments are @Pos_Enteros and @Pos_Decimales which specify how many Integers and Decimal places you want to show for the Number you pass as input argument.
*/

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server before 2012 which does not include the FORMAT function, create this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FormatCurrency(@value numeric(30,2))
    RETURNS varchar(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @NumAsChar VARCHAR(50)
        SET @NumAsChar = '$' + CONVERT(varchar(50), CAST(@Value AS money),1)
        RETURN @NumAsChar
    END
```

select dbo.FormatCurrency(12345678)
returns $12,345,678.00

Drop the $ if you just want commas.