# A more concise way to format COUNT result with thousands separator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

## Goal

Format a `COUNT` result to a common format (e.g. `###,##0`) in a concise statement and without UDF's.

## I've Tried

I am currently using something like this, though it leaves two decimals **and** is clunky:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(COUNT([id]) AS MONEY), 1) FROM tbl
```

The reason I went that direction is because it was the only standard formatting option I could find when reading through the [CAST and CONVERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) documentation from MSDN.

I don't really like it, but it limps along since these numbers are simply copied and pasted into other text editors and such after the T-SQL runs. They do of course have to be formatted by hand to remove the decimals in some places.

## Research and Restrictions

Of course you could build a user-defined function, like this [one on this blog](http://novicksoftware.com/UDFofWeek/Vol1/T-SQL-UDF-Volume-1-Number-48-formatnumber.htm), but I have a restriction that keeps me from building UDF's for this purpose.

After some additional research I found that if I were using SQL 2012 I could use a new T-SQL [`FORMAT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function, alas, I'm restricted to 2008 R2. This of course leverages a different platform as it's a .NET interface. :D

I am also aware of this solution: [Format a number with commas but without decimals in SQL Server 2008 R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207075/format-a-number-with-commas-but-without-decimals-in-sql-server-2008-r2)

Comment: I'm sure you're aware of this, and I don't want to question anyone with so much rep, but this really is handled *so* much easier in your application, unless you're absolutely hell-bent on doing it in your SQL query

Comment: Why don't you perform this formatting on the client, e.g. C# has very good functionality in Format() and ToString(). Also [please stop declaring `varchar` without length. It's lazy and dangerous](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, I'm restricted to `T-SQL` in this case. I would, as you stated, do it in .NET if I had the luxury. However, this is a massive conversion script that must be executed on the SQL server because of restrictions out of my control.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I'm restricted to using `T-SQL` in this case. I would love to, of course, leverage the .NET framework here to make my life a little easier. If I could do the entire conversion using .NET I would, but alas, I've been restricted by the powers that be.

Comment: So what is wrong with the existing solution? You want something more concise? More efficient? Something else? If it ain't broke, I don't think you're going to find anything "better" other than formatting on the client.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, yes, I'm looking for something more concise. I've done a lot of research already, and I've tried to update that section of my question with it, and I too feel I'm up against a wall. However, I thought that some of my peers up here might know something I don't.

Comment: I don't think you can make anything much shorter, no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not the most elegant, but you can remove the trailing .00 with replace.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(COUNT([id]) AS MONEY), 1), '.00', '')
FROM tbl
```

Comment: +1, my initial thought was to use `LEFT(zzz,len(zzz)-3)`, but this seams better

Comment: I do this with count(*) but it converts the result in a totally different number

Answer (score 13):

Even though the question author was stuck on SQL Server 2008R2, this is a concise and efficient solution should you be blessed with **SQL Server 2012 or newer**.

## No digits after decimal point (rounded)

```
SELECT FORMAT(COUNT([id]), N'N0')
FROM [tbl]
```

**Example output**

```
53,234,568
```

## One digit after decimal point

```
SELECT FORMAT(COUNT([id]), N'N1')
FROM [tbl]
```

**Example output**

```
53,234,567.9
```

## Two digits after decimal point

```
SELECT FORMAT(COUNT([id]), N'N2')
FROM [tbl]
```

**Example output**

```
53,234,567.89
```

(etc.)

## Two digits after decimal point, no thousands separator

```
SELECT FORMAT(COUNT([id]), N'#.00')
FROM [tbl]
```

**Example output**

```
53234567.89
```

Comment: This should be answer.

Comment: This is the best answer!