# How can i format money in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, currency

Data is 1128,5000 as money in table . 

I need to make it in 1.128,50 format. 

Every 3 digits before comma want to add dot.

Comment: What culture is your SQL instance and which culture do you want to display it in? I ask because for me a typical money format would be £1128.50

Comment: Why do you need to format the data while quering it? Leave the formatting to the application which will display the data.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only built in formatting supported in 2008 always uses `,` as the thousands separator and `.` as the decimal separator, no matter what language settings are in force. It would almost certainly be easier to do this formatting at another level, outside of T-SQL, as Pred suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in T-SQL but it's **ugly**:

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    CONVERT(varchar(20),
    CONVERT(money,1128.5000), --If you already have money you don't need this bit
    1) --x,xxx.xx
    ,'.','?')
    ,',','.')
    ,'?',',')
```

Result:

```
1.128,50
```

Comment: ok, if it's ugly in t-sql then how can i make it with c sharp or with javascript?
can you help?

Comment: @ds.zo - if you have it in, say, a `decimal` and what you've asked for reflects your current culture, it would just be (in C#, assuming `d` is the `decimal`) `d.ToString("N")`. If it's not reflective of your current culture, one way would be `d.ToString("N", new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalDigits = 2, NumberDecimalSeparator = ",", NumberGroupSeparator = ".", NumberGroupSizes = new [] { 3 } });` which looks long but at least is *clear* on what you're doing, as opposed to the above SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,I borrowed from [Mitch Wheat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207075/format-a-number-with-commas-but-without-decimals-in-sql-server-2008-r2/13207166#13207166)

```
declare @price as nvarchar(50)
declare @money varchar(50)
declare @pos int

set @price='1128,5000'
set @money = convert(varchar(50), CAST(@price AS money), 1)
declare @SAS NVARCHAR(50)
set @SAS=convert(varchar(20), CAST(@price AS money),1)
set stuff((sTUFF(@SAS,(len(@SAS) - (LEN(@SAS)-2)),1,'.'))  ,CHARINDEX(',', @SAS),1,'')
```