# How to change my SQL Pivot query syntax so that the output includes comma and zero decimals?

Tags: sql-server, format, pivot

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I am running the following T-SQL pivot query:

```
USE MyDatabase

SELECT PropertyCode, ISNULL([AUGUST 2015],0) AS 'August 2015' FROM
(
 SELECT [PropertyCode], [MTH], [Package Revenue Excl VAT]

 FROM [RSDLIST]) m

 PIVOT (SUM([Package Revenue Excl VAT]) FOR [MTH] IN

 ([AUGUST 2015]

 )) AS PVTTABLE
```

An extract of my output is shown below:

```
 PropertyCode   August 2015
    Smith        15071923.019032
    Jones            2152483.164654
    Steeve           7136836.891117
```

I need to format the second column so that the output becomes:

```
     PropertyCode     August 2015
        Smith         15,071,923
        Jones     2,152,483
        Steeve    7,136,836
```

I've had a look at the answers provided here :
[Format a number with commas but without decimals in SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207075/format-a-number-with-commas-but-without-decimals-in-sql-server-2008-r2)

and this one from Microsoft: [Format (T-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

I've tried the first one by replacing [Package Revenue Excl VAT] at line 3 with the following: 
    `CONVERT(varchar,CAST(a.[Package Revenue Excl VAT] AS MONEY),1) AS 'Pkg Rev'`

However, since the values have been converted into a varchar, they can't be used in the Pivot query!

Comment: run the format code after the numerical pivot. You can use a derived table, CTE or temp table for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
--First
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(CAST(15071923.019032 as decimal(18,0)) AS money), 1)
-- Second
select replace(convert(varchar,CAST(CAST(15071923.019032 as decimal(18,0)) AS money),1), '.00','')
-- Third
SELECT Format(15071923.019032, '##,##0')
```

try according your code

```
select PropertyCode, ISNULL(Format(15071923.019032, '##,##0') ,0) AS 'August 2015' FROM ....
```

Comment: I am a bit confused by your answer. Do you mean I need to go through these 3 steps to achieve what I'm after or do I need to use only one of these 3 options?

Comment: @user3115933 NO this is three way to achieve , values

Comment: I've tried all 3 options but none of them allow me to use the "Package Revenue excl VAT" in my PIVOT Query.

Comment: @user3115933 try like that `select ISNULL(Format(15071923.019032, '##,##0') ,0) AS 'August 2015'`