# Removing decimals from Number keeping thousands delimiters in Sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a number  like : `12345.678`

I want it to  be like : `12,345` ( removing the rest !)

one solution of *adding thousands seperator* is  :

```
 select convert(varchar(100), cast(12345.678 as money), 1)
```

which yields  : `12,345.68`

Now I should remove the `.68`

I stumbled upon a beautiful solution with  **[parseName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx)**   :

```
 select    parsename(convert(varchar(100), cast(12345.678 as money), 1),2)
```

which yields  : `12,345`

Question  : is there a *better* solution for this problem ? ( maybe without involving other functions/string manipulations ? )

Comment: this could help: [How do I format a number with commas in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377352/how-do-i-format-a-number-with-commas-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no easy way of doing this in SQL server 2008.  SQL Server 2012 introduced the [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28FORMAT_TSQL%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1%29;k%28MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-TSQL%29&rd=true) function, which enables you to do the following:

```
SELECT FORMAT(12345.67, '#,###')
```

(although this will round the number to 12,346)

Formatting results is something that is not normally in the scope of a database - it's something which should be left to your front-end program/web site/report/spreadsheet etc.  However, if you really need to be doing this in SQL Server, I suspect your solution is as close as you're going to get, unless you use CLR Integration to link to the String.Format function from .NET.

If you do go with your solution using parseName, be aware that it may not work internationally (e.g. in parts of Europe where `,` is used as a decimal separator).  This may not be an issue for you, but if it is then you'll need a solution which allows you to explicitly control the formatting.

Comment: I didnt tag my question as 2012. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Parsename is indeed an inventive solution.  I have always been using

```
select replace(convert(varchar,cast(floor(12345.678) as money),1), '.00', '');
--     parsename(convert(varchar,cast(12345.678 as money),1), 2);
```

Although it's longer. But maybe a direct replacement is faster than a parse routine? In any case, it's not better in the sense that even if it ran 21ns faster, in the greater scheme of things, what are you trying to improve on with such a question?

Comment: @Royi This should've been the answer!

Answer (score 2):

use floor() to convert it to integer first :

```
select convert(varchar(100), cast(floor(12345.68) as money), 1)
```

Comment: **sorry but its not what i meant. i dont want the `.00`. ( question says - "REMOVING**)

Answer (score 0):

I support Richards comment that this is normally done in the 'presentation' layer. Why do you need to format this in SQL Server? Are you viewing reports directly in SQL Server? Usually the first thing someone does is copy and paste into Excel.

Anyway If you can always wrap the expression above in a some more string functions:

```
select replace(
convert(
    varchar(100), 
    cast(floor(12345.68) as money),
    1
),'.00','')
```

There are still possible bugs in this, and again I do not recommend this is done at SQL Server unless you are generating COBOL-like text reports.