# SQL Server 2008 thousands separator for a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column called `TotalArea` and its format is `numeric (12,2)`.

I want it to display the numbers with a thousand separator so when I

```
select TotalArea from table
```

to show me a format like `1,234.00`.

How could I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a number with commas in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377352/how-do-i-format-a-number-with-commas-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(MONEY, TotalArea), 1), '.00', '') 
FROM table
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(123456 AS MONEY), 1) AS VARCHAR)
FROM table
```

Comment: +1 because it's correct, but please don't do this. @MattWhitfield has it absolutely nailed.

Comment: Only do this if your number casts into a money type. @dasiimwe has the better answer. Float values will error

Comment: Float values cast fine, and if you're stuck with SQL Server 2008 then this is proabably the best choice.     `declare @f float = 12345.67890;  
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(@f AS Money), 1)`

Answer (score 55):

```
SELECT FORMAT(12345,'#,0.00');

SELECT FORMAT(TotalArea,'#,0.00') from table;
```

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634206(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This is the best answer as this works -- SELECT FORMAT(2222222222222222222222222,'#,0.00')

Comment: Supported only from SQL Server 2012 onwards. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b4090663-6805-46f5-b84f-81e5eb90da30/format-works-in-2012-but-not-in-2008-what-am-i-missing?forum=transactsql

Comment: Thanks, very helpful

Comment: Simple, elegant, correct. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: The MS docs for [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) say "This function cannot be remoted since it depends on the presence of the CLR." What exactly does "remoting" a function like this mean?

Answer (score 21):

Formatting numbers for display is something that should be done in the display layer, and not within the database. So, in whatever application this data ends up being used, you should format it there. Management Studio, unfortunately, does not offer much control in this regard.

Comment: What about if you want standardised XML data formatting?  I manage formatting standards in the database, and this propagates to all clients, be it web, mobile, etc.  And BTW, FORMAT(number,'#,0') gives you separators, not sure why anyone would use replace(convert(convert()))???? Not efficient in my view when doing 1M+records...

Comment: @ArvinAmir - I would contend that formatting of XML is only necessary for humans - computers consume it the same whether it has a bunch of whitespace in it or not. So I would say that sort of formatting still should be done at the point of display.

Comment: If I'm querying directly the database, for example using a query sheet in SSMS, the display layer is together with the database layer, so asking for a human-readable format is perfectly legit.

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus - using SSMS as a display layer isn't really 'legit'. A stop-gap? Sure. A long term solution? Hell no.

Comment: @MattWhitfield "isn't really 'legit'"? What about Report Services? Obviously, it depends of the application you're developing: I don't like to use a relational database for more than tables and FKs (I hate SP, functions, triggers, etc), but if you don't have a multi-layer application and you want to use just SSMS to handle your data... well, that's fine

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus - I'll have to respectfully disagree, a database is not an application, and SSMS is not an end-user query tool. Reporting Services offers much more control over formatting.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is for sql server 2008 but if you have sql server 2012+, you can use format like so:

```
SELECT FORMAT(12345.5634, 2);
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_format.asp

Comment: Here's a link to the Microsoft Docs for T-SQL's FORMAT function: https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql. The link above is for MySQL.

Comment: This gives an error: `Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 131 Argument data type int is invalid for argument 2 of format function.` Presumably you're answering a different question :) This one is about SQL Server.

Comment: This is answer for mysql, not worked in T-SQl/MS SQL.