# Display comma for column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using this query to display a column with money datatype and how could I insert comma on top of this.

```
'$ '+CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(decimal(10,0), CONVERT(money,B2.Total_Amount)),1) as Total_Amount,
'$ '+CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(decimal(10,0), CONVERT(money,B2.Monthly_Amount )),1) as Monthly_Amount
```

Output

```
1500
```

Expected Output:

```
1,500
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Vicky What is the use of `CONVERT(decimal(10,0)` here

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 thousands separator for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857331/sql-server-2008-thousands-separator-for-a-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this

```
'$ '+ Replace(CONVERT(varchar,CAST(B2.Total_Amount AS money),1) ,'.00','') as Total_Amount,
'$ '+ Replace(CONVERT(varchar, CAST(B2.Monthly_Amount As money),1),'.00','') as Monthly_Amount
```

If B2.Monthly_Amount is

```
1987654321
```

Then the Op will be

```
1,987,654,321
```

Comment: I do not want to show that .00 after the value and I have to remove that decimal

Comment: I get this error Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: @Vicky It's better to go with Replace function..see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with this:

`select replace(convert(varchar,convert(Money, B2.Total_Amount),1),'.00','')`

BUT YOU SHOULDN'T DO IT

thats part of the display layer

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @amount money=10000.00

select replace(convert(varchar,convert(Money, @amount),1),'.00','') =>10,000
```

In sql 2012 you can use [Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

```
FORMAT(@amount ,'#,0.0000')
```