# Conversion of String to int not getting desired format

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, casting, crystal-reports

I want to convert a string to int like this:
`CAST(TestSth3.Emp_Code AS int)`

I need output as 1234 in crystal report, shows me correctly when i get the output from database, but in Crystal it again converts to 1,234 instead of 1234.

I am using vb.net 2008 and SQL server.

Comment: what is the value of TEstSth3.Emp_Code ??is it 1,234 ???

Comment: declare  @num varchar(10) ='1234'
select CAST(@num AS int) it will give 1234 not 1,234 .. where from you get 1,234 ?? what is the value of your string ??/

Comment: my empcode is string value when i execute the above line the value display in my crystal report i get the empcode as 1,234 but i need the report as 1234.

Comment: ok i got it i am asking you what is the value of that string is it 1234 or 1,234 ???

Comment: @user2082374 you may take one look at either my answer or at  Arunprasanth KV's answer, both are correct and good enough to solve your issue i guess!

Comment: thanks for answer the string value is without comma(1234) but when i see in crystal report it gives me 1,234

Comment: I think that your problem is not at database level, rather at crystal report level. Maybe you can check how crystal report render integers, and check options for field representing the number.

Comment: check my answer now and let me know if you solves your problem

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to try this solution, Replace ',' to '' in the string

Take a look on below code

```
CAST(REPLACE(TestSth3.Emp_Code, ',', '') AS int) As Clm
```

Comment: my empcode is string value when i execute the above line the value display in my crystal report i get the empcode as 1,234 but i need the report as 1234 Still same out put

Comment: @user2082374 i think you need to take a look at Crystal report where you are receiving data from the SQL server, i don't have more idea about crystal reports, but i worked on SSRS, so i guess it solves your issue if you take a look at CrystalReport instead

Answer (score 1):

it is unclear your question i just point out some facts here

if your string is 1234 
then when you try `select cast(yournum,int)` will give you the correct result
example

```
select cast('1234'as int) as num
```

will results

```
1234
```

or if your string is something like `1,234` 
then 
try the following it will give results

```
declare  @num varchar(10) ='1,234'

select CONVERT(int, replace(@num,',',''))as number
```

or

```
select CAST(replace(@num,',','') AS int)as number2
```

both results `1234`

also you need to double check `TestSth3.Emp_Code` what is that ?? is it a parameter ?? 
if yes then need @before that and i think it is not possible to create a parameter name including .(dot) so double check that too.

**UPDATE**

if the problem based on crystal report then follow below steps

> Right mouse click on that field, and select "Format object". Select
>   "Custom Style" in the Style list, and click "Customize". Untick
>   "Thousands Separator", and any other unwanted formatting.
>
> Failing that, you could try selecting the field and deleting the ","
>   value from the property "ThousandSeperator" in your properties window.

or use below formula

```
CStr(YourField, 0, '')
```

Comment: my empcode is string value when i execute the above line the value display in my crystal report i get the empcode as 1,234 but i need the report as 1234, still same

Comment: show me more code, or else tell me what is the value of your TestSth3.Emp_Code

Comment: sql 2008 in sql output no problem but i can't get in Crystal report

Comment: @user2082374 i think you need to take a look at Crystal report where you are receiving data from the SQL server, i don't have more idea about crystal reports, but i worked on SSRS, so i guess it solves your issue if you take a look at CrystalReport instead

Comment: yes i got you now...if you are usinng ssrs then you got the same result ..but in cristal report need to check ..let you know after checking that

Answer (score 0):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857331/sql-server-2008-thousands-separator-for-a-column) summarises the problem much better. @MattWhitfield says:

> Formatting numbers for display is something that should be done in the
>   display layer, and not within the database. So, in whatever
>   application this data ends up being used, you should format it there.
>   Management Studio, unfortunately, does not offer much control in this
>   regard.

**Edit:** Integers don't have formats. E.g. Six eggs are formatted as eggs, not digits, but they are still 6. The formatting has nothing to do with the number. However if you want to **display** the integer in a particular format (with or without thousands separator - commas), then convert it back to a string again *in the report or VB form*, not in the database (or leave it as a string since it's already a string).

Comment: what is display layer ??? in sql also we can do these things , what will do if you need to do some type of formatting with sql table values ???

Comment: Why are you converting it to an integer? Why not just leave it as a string?

Comment: this question you should ask to questioner not to me, it may be a requirement

Comment: if it is string when i sort, the sorting is not in order

Comment: Oh sorry @Arunprasanth, you are right. I didn't read who posted the comment

Comment: @user2082374, so sort by the integer, and display the string: SELECT TestSth3.Emp_Code ORDER BY CAST(TestSth3.Emp_Code AS int)

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to use crystal report functions:

```
ToNumber(TestSth3.Emp_Code)
```