# Style argument in Convert() function not adding comma

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to convert a numeric field to money data type by way of the convert() function, but it doesn't add the comma.

Using this :

```
convert(money, smlunitprice, 1) as smltotalprice
```

Gives me the following output :

```
smltotalprice
---------------------
20980.00
8773.03
7122.81
7122.81
```

I've used this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.90).aspx) for reference, but is this only possible when converting FROM money not TO money? Is there another way to add commas when converting from numeric to money?

I'm using SSMS to access a SQL Server 2000 DBMS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I format a number with commas in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377352/how-do-i-format-a-number-with-commas-in-t-sql)

Comment: numeric types (such as `money`, etc) don't *have* a user controllable format - it's just `money`. The only way to have a particular string representation is to convert from these types to a string (such as `varchar`). Thus, it doesn't make *sense* to ask about it applying when converting TO `money`.

Comment: Unfortunately the money datatype doesn't adhere to that formatting, if you want to format it with commas, you need to use the method in the comment above and convert the value to varchar to display it.