# Display money with decimal in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having some number in DB table column, i have written stored procedure to format that number. The requirement is i need to display the number with comma and decimal points. I have tried below, but only comma is coming.. any solutions,

```
PARSENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(TotalAmount/1000 as MONEY),1),2)
```

Actual result: 1,134

Expected result: 1,134.0

I want to do this in SQL server itself.

Comment: "I want to do this in SQL server itself" No, you must do it on client side. There is no reason to do it on Sql server.

Comment: yeah..i know, but i need to do in sql, bcoz client requirement is like this..

Comment: Client tells you implementation details? Strange!

Comment: Answered here [How do I format a number with commas in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377352/how-do-i-format-a-number-with-commas-in-t-sql)

Comment: Do it in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish currency formatting as:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(5555 AS money), 1)
```

but i would suggest doing such formatting on the front end, not on the data side