# Sql Server select money with comma

Tags: sql-server, currency, currency-formatting

I have **Payment** table in ms sql server.

Payment table has below column type of **money**

```
Salary
```

**Salary** column has below values

```
1495.88

2235.08

719.59

15.75

9.59

0.00

NULL

97.77
```

When i select query as below,

```
select Salary from Payment where
```

**Result** must be below

```
1,495,88

2,235,08

719,59

15,75

9,59

0,00

NULL

97,77
```

I tried below

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(Salary AS money), 1) from  Payment
```

this did not work for me.

How can i get money as comma format

thanks

Comment: Do not do formatting in SQL, do it in your report, in Excel, or whatever client you are using.

Comment: I need to convert in t sql side thanks

Comment: can you explain why it needs to be done sql side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a number with commas in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377352/how-do-i-format-a-number-with-commas-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your client app to format result, but if you wish you can do it like :

```
DECLARE @m MONEY  = 10000000.12
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @m, 1) AS Result
```

Output:

```
Result
10,000,000.12
```

For dot:

```
DECLARE @m MONEY  = 10000000.12
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @m, 5), '.', ',') AS Result
```

Output:

```
Result
10,000,000,12
```