# How to add commas to a value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to add to the result value inside a column commas?

I mean for example I create new value:

```
insert into dbo.SAPID (TEST2)
Values (110)
```

I want the value to be with commas='110' inside the column result set.

Comment: Some sample data, and expected result please!

Comment: Hard to say what you want with no example data, but maybe this is what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377352/how-do-i-format-a-number-with-commas-in-t-sql. However, it likely would be better practice to do this in the presentation layer.

Comment: do you mean `'quotes'` rather than `,commas,`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into dbo.SAPID (TEST2)
Values (char(39) + '110' + char(39))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your request. It seems like `TEST2` is an Integer and you would like to return a string with single quotes surrounding it.

To do this you can cast the value when selected and append the quote:

```
SELECT '''' + CAST( TEST2 AS NVARCHAR(10) ) + '''' FROM SAPID
```

Comment: Where do you append the commas?

Comment: I believe the OP is mistaken over the terminology between `quotes` and `commas`.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what Leonid is going for with the commas. But depending on how Leonid stores his data either my solution or Nepali's will work. Chances are if it is left in its present state it will get more down votes and removed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are thinking of single quotes `''` like you provided in your example above:

> I want the value to be with commas='110'

In that case, you could just do something like this:

```
--your column in the table will need to be a string instead of int
create table dbo.SAPID (TEST2 nvarchar(10));

--insert string value with single quotes 
insert into dbo.SAPID(TEST2)
VALUES ('''' + '110' + '''');

--select statement
select * from dbo.SAPID
```

Single quote is an escape character in SQL much like other languages.**Single quotes are escaped by doubling them up**, just as shown in above example.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/779a5/1/0)