# how to change format of amount number in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

how to change a format of a number to 1,214,378.00

If i have a number 1214378.00
how can I change it into 1,214,378.00 ? 
any help :)

Comment: Don't, please don't. You can change the way the number displays in your settings, but if you change that number to a string you will cause all manner of headaches for yourself and anyone who tries to use the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377352/how-do-i-format-a-number-with-commas-in-t-sql Possible duplicate. Answer here